# Why does %TEMP% resolve to a non-deterministic path of the form %TEMP\<digit>?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, temp

I have a Windows Server 2008 32 bit and when I'm typing %temp% it takes me to ..AppData\Local\Temp\1\ or ..AppData\Local\Temp\2 instead of ..AppData\Local\Temp

I've already checked the Environment Variables and they are ok.

I'm asking that because I have an application that's supposed to copy files to %temp%\my application and instead it copies the files to %temp%\1\my application

Does someone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Explanation, discussion, workarounds, etc, all under the Old New Thing article [Why does the name of my TEMP directory keep changing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/25/10119675.aspx) - it ensures multiple terminal services sessions for the same user don't (by default) share a temp directory.

> The problem lay in the [Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Temporary folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759190%28WS.10%29.aspx) group policy. If you don't select **Do not use temporary folders per session**, then these TEMP subdirectories are created. There is also [a knowledge base article describing the registry keys behind these group policies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243215).

Personally, I find the first comment in reply to be the most useful:

> Why does it matter if the temp location jumps around anyway, it's temporary!

### See also

- [Use separate temporary folders for each session](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759190%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, im now understand it... , ive changed the target folder instead of the %temp% folder

Comment: Why does it matter if it changes?  Because sometimes two programs must rendezvous via a file in the TEMP directory.  Not being able to predict the value makes it harder.

Comment: @e40 - if the two programs are running in the *same* session, they'll observe the same value. If the two programs are running in *different* sessions, then any interaction between them is probably a bug.

Comment: I've run into a case where I end up with a /2 temp folder, but somehow Windows is not creating that folder. So a bunch of stuff starts failing. Some apps - like Process Explorer won't even run as it extracts and runs from temp folder.

Comment: This was a weird one to try and Google but I'm glad I found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables have 4 contexts:

*(do Win+R then type regedit to find the paths below)*

1. System variables (`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`)
2. User variables (`HKCU\Environment`)
3. Process variables (not stored in the registry)
4. Volatile variables (`HKCU\VolatileEnvironment`)

ref: https://rakhesh.com/windows/temp-environment-variable-has-a-2-or-other-number-after-it/

When the Group Policy `Do not use temporary folders per session` isn't configured or isn't set to Enabled, the system will generate two Volatile Environment variables `TEMP` & `TMP` with the same value of the current user's `TEMP` variable with the addition of an incremental number at the end of the TEMP folder (increments each time the user logs in, check @Damien's answer for details)

If you set the group policy `Do not use temporary folders per session` to enabled, this behavior will not occur.