# no path or pathfile specified on the command line: TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

when I try to update my SVN repository with Tortoies SVN Client I have following error, 
"no path or pathfile specified on the command line"

recently I had machine upgrade to windows 7. could anyone please help out ?

Comment: Try using the relocate command in the tortoisesvn menu to update the URL to the repository, then try the update command again?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all the files located under the following directories:

- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
- c:\windows\TEMP

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing this error on a Windows Server, and you are connected via RDP, you might get this error because the %TEMP% directory doesn't resolve to an existing path: [Why does %TEMP% resolve to a non-deterministic path of the form %TEMP\<digit>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521277/why-does-temp-resolve-to-a-non-deterministic-path-of-the-form-temp-digit)

Signing out and reconnecting fixed this for me.

Comment: In my case there was a file named "2" within the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` directory, causing %TEMP% to resolve to a file instead of a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was with machine, which was missing some start up scripts.
due to machine upgrade I lost my start up scripts and it caused error in my SCM set up.

This could be close now.

thanks,
Shreedhar